# Do I need transit visa in Istanbul, Turkey?

Tags: schengen, transit-visas, pakistani-citizens, business-travel

I will be traveling from Pakistan to Slovenia by business visa (short term  Schengen). I will be traveling from Pakistan to Istanbul and from Istanbul to Ljubljana (Slovenia). Do I need to get Istanbul transit visa? I need information for both cases i.e going outside of the airport or staying inside the airport. I'm traveling for the first time and I am a Pakistani Citizen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't leave the airport then you do not need a visa.

If you plan to leave the airport you will need to apply for an eVisa from the Turkish government from : [evisa.gov.tr](https://www.evisa.gov.tr/en/) as they no longer provide visas upon arrival.